# unexpected result of case condition in sql server 2017

Tags: sql-server, compatibility, sql-server-2017

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(STAFFING_PRIORITY_CODE,'') = 'Billable' AND   
   RESOURCE_TYPE in ('confirmed','provisional')AND PROJECTTYPE IN (select   
   ProjectType from OracleProjectTypeClass WHERE ShortName IN ('FB','TM'))  
   THEN CAST(ISNULL([%_WORK_ALLOCATION],0) AS decimal(18,2))   
   ELSE 0 END as [Billable]From [DBO].BenchDashboard where EMPLOYEE_ID=107500
```

> This query result is:-
>     Billable
>     100.00

we add one more column in select statement:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(STAFFING_PRIORITY_CODE,'')='Billable'ANDRESOURCE_TYPE in('confirmed','provisional') 
   AND PROJECTTYPE IN (select ProjectType from OracleProjectTypeClass WHERE ShortName IN ('FB','TM'))
   THEN CAST(ISNULL([%_WORK_ALLOCATION],0) AS decimal(18,2)) ELSE 0 END as [Billable]
    --added column
    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(STAFFING_PRIORITY_CODE,'') = 'Buffer' AND RESOURCE_TYPE in ('confirmed','provisional') 
    AND PROJECTTYPE IN (select ProjectType from OracleProjectTypeClass WHERE ShortName IN ('FB','TM'))
    THEN CAST(ISNULL([%_WORK_ALLOCATION],0) AS decimal(18,2)) ELSE 0 END as [Buffer]From [DBO].BenchDashboard where EMPLOYEE_ID=107500
```

> Its give result
>     Billable|Buffer
>     0.0     |     0.00

data for first column(Billable) changes from 100 to 0 why ?
1)This Sql code work properly in sql server 2008r2 or compatibility level 100
But problem occured in compatibility level 140 or sql server 2017

> result should be:-
>      Billable|Buffer
>     100.00|0.00

Thanks in advance
  Please Find 
[image: screen shots]

Comment: If you hover your mouse over the tag `case-statement`, you'll see the line "Do not use this tag". Can you provide a [mcve] which shows this result?

Comment: Is this the exact code? In your second example, your two columns have the same name. What happens if you make the second column `Buffer2`?

Comment: first column name is billable and second one is buffer

Comment: Adding another column never affects another column. Is that the only change you made?

Comment: I added one screen shots,when i remove subquery then it properly work on 2017

Comment: Changing the compat level changes the optimizer. Check any relevant difference in execution plans. Pretty much the only way this query could "legitimately" fail (i.e. not a bug in the engine) is if `[dbo].BenchDashboard` is a view with a query that gives nondeterministic results.